# monitor memory usage with R parallel

Tags: r, memory-management, parallel-processing

Is there a way to monitor *true* memory usage when using R parallel, particularly with SOCK-type clusters?

I tried with `profvis` but it returns a smaller memory footprint with a parallel analogue of the serial statement. For instance,

```
lapply(...)
parLapply(...)
```

where `(...)` is the same statement.

As far as I understand, memory usage should be equal-to or larger with a parallel statement because data needs to be copied (at least for SOCK clusters). Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to monitor it precisely? What I usually do is just looking at the global system monitor of my computer during execution.

Comment: Hi FPrive, I'd like to have a record of it mostly. I'll think about different ways of monitoring memory usage on each worker by exporting custom functions.

Comment: Have you used `profvis` for the whole script or used it inside (like inside the foreach call)?

Comment: I `profvis` the whole script. If you're suggesting to put it inside each `foreach`, it might work, but I'll have to test it.

Comment: Yeap. As the inside work is done by other R sessions, I think it is normal that you don't have the whole memory usage.